# Client Server EOF Error

Tags: java, sockets

My application communicates between a server and a client using DataInputStream and DataOutputStream. The client will be requests from a website to my application, so I created a test client to test input that could come from the website.

The method I decided to use would be that the client would send an integer first deciding the size of the data to be sent and then it would send the data. So, I was testing this method and it worked for the first string of data, but not the second and gave me an EOF error on the second try. I understand why it gave me an EOF because the client closed the connection, but I still have not read the incoming bytes, so the stream should still have more to read from.

Client Code:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9000);
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
os.writeInt("Test String".length());
os.write("Test String".getBytes());
os.flush();
os.writeInt("String".length());
os.write("String".getBytes());
os.flush();
os.close();
socket.close();
```

Server Code:

```
byte[] data;

try{
    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        client.setSoTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Client connected with IP: " + client.getInetAddress());

    data = readNextPacket(input);
    if(!(new String(data).contains(PROTOCOL_HEADER)))
        throw new IOException("Invalid request from client.");
    else
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Valid header: " + new String(data));

    data = readNextPacket(input);
    logger.log(Level.INFO, new String(data));
}catch(IOException e){
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
}finally{
    try {
        client.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "FINISHED");
}
```

readNextPacket Method:

```
private byte[] readNextPacket(DataInputStream stream) throws IOException{
    int bytesToRead = stream.readInt();
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    if(bytesToRead <= MAX_BYTES){
        byte[] data = new byte[bytesToRead];

        while(stream.read(data) != -1 && os.size() < bytesToRead){
            os.write(data);
        }
    }

    return os.toByteArray();
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
at com.schmidt73.bidwriter.handlers.SocketHandler.readNextPacket(SocketHandler.java:1)
at com.schmidt73.bidwriter.handlers.SocketHandler.parse(SocketHandler.java:16)
at com.schmidt73.bidwriter.handlers.SocketHandler.start(SocketHandler.java:43)
at com.schmidt73.bidwriter.BidWriter.main(BidWriter.java:21)
```

Comment: I suggest you use java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject() instead this way of first send the lenght... here a tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/objectoutputstream_writeobject.htm ; and nothing wrong if you do not want use brackets in conditional operator, but is a good practice.

Comment: Yes, but I will not be reading data from Java objects, so I prefer to use readInt() and writeInt() as they just convert the first four bytes read to an int. However, this does not seem to be the problem in my application and shouldn't be.

Comment: The code you've written in `readNextPacket()` isn't correct, but I suggest you write your strings with `writeUTF()` and read them with `readUTF()`, instead of replicating what they do by hand, incorrectly.

Comment: Actually `writeUTF()` and `readUTF()` use a completely different protocol than what I am using. [Look Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String)). My method is much simpler and when communicating with a website is my preference. Also why isn't it correct? @EJP

Comment: @EJP You are right that I am doing another read if unsuccessful, but I am putting the contents of the first read into the ByteArrayOutputStream and using that to count the number of bytes I have read, therefore I am losing no bytes. Also I don't use the API methods because the person writing the client will not be using Java and prefers the method I use.

Comment: I'm aware it uses a different protocol, but only slightly: 16-bit length word instead of 32, and a more reliable way of mapping chars to bytes than you are using. Yours is certainly not 'much simpler'. It isn't even correct, because if the first read doesn't fill the buffer you can read beyond the end of the data on the second and subsequent reads. Try `readFully()` if you can't use the APIs that are provided for the purpose, and make sure to specify the charset when converting between bytes and chars.

Comment: You are right it isn't much simpler, but it should work as even if the first read doesn't fill the buffer the nth read will. That is why I use the ByteArrayOutputStream.

Comment: Sigh. If you don't read the entire buffer the first time, you redo the read, with the same parameter, which can read the same amount of data as you tried to read the first time, so you can end up with more data than you meant to read, i.e. whatever you read the first time plus the entire buffer, or whatever, the second time. You aren't constraining  the read length correctly, i.e. at all, on the subsequent reads. But you don't need any subsequent reads: you only need `readFully()`. When you've tried it let us know.

Comment: @EJP you're right readFully() works, but I am just confused because if there are 20 bytes in a buffer and I try to read 20 and it only returns me 10 then there are 10 left in the buffer, so when I try to read 20 more it will read the remaining 10 in the buffer and give me those.

Comment: How can `read()` possibly know there are only 10 bytes left in the byte array, when you don't provide the offset and length parameters? All it can see is the byte array itself and its length.

Comment: @EJP Okay that makes sense. I for some reason thought that it would work that way even though there was more information queued up from my multiple `write` calls. Thanks a ton for your help, I just had trouble understanding that I was reading too many bytes. Also, I like to do things myself before resorting to higher level APIs to do the work for me. I need to start at the lowest level and work my way up and that is why I like C so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so basically my `readNextPacket()` method would read more data than specified if the entire buffer wasn't read the first time. So, I changed some of the code to fix it by adding an offset and subtracting the amount I've already read to the `read()` method. However, I realized that would be basically copying the `readFully()` method and there is no reason to do that, so I just implemented that into the `readNextPacket()` method.

Here is the new working code:

```
private byte[] readNextPacket(DataInputStream stream) throws IOException{
    int bytesToRead = stream.readInt();
    byte[] data = new byte[bytesToRead];

    stream.readFully(data);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Why the MAX_BYTES test? If it fails, you don't read anything except the length word, silently, and the following invocations of this method will fail in bizarre ways. Best to just let whatever happens happen, and fail immediately, rather than creating a debugging nightmare for later on.